# How to argue range of a function using intermediate value theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g(x)= 99x^3 + 999x^2 + 9999$, where $x$ is any real number. I know the image of an interval under continuous function is still an interval and this function is unbounded when $x$ goes to infinity. But how can I prove the range of this function is $\mathbb{R}$? Besides intermediate value theorem, is there any theorem I shall use?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: You just need to check that $\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} g(x) = \pm \infty$, and then yes, intermediate value theorem is all you need.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Do you mean first I check the limits of this function, then I use intermediate value theorem to show the image is an unbounded interval. So the range should be R? I am stil not quite sure about the detailed steps. Do you mind writing it down? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

we have $f(x)=99x^3 +999x^2+9999$ now is there an $x_0$ for any real $y$ such that $f(x_0)=y=99(x_0)^3 +999(x_0)^2+9999$ wouldn't that be the same as saying the equation $99x^3 +999x^2+9999-y=0$ always has a solution for any real value of y? is that true? [Cardano](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method).

Comment: This is in response to the question whether there is another theorem you can use.

Comment: I think you are right. But though it seems trivial, I still don't know a good way to prove the equation always has a real solution.

Comment: There is a link to the formula in the answer. It is called  cardano's method.